# How to append two objects data in FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, barcode, php-7, fpdf

I am trying to create PDF as below Image.

I have a separate code create PDF with text as written below  and another code which create Barcode using this code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require '/home/rahul/Downloads/fpdf181/fpdf.php';

require('/var/www/html/test_barcode/code128.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();  
$pdf->AddPage();  
$pdf->Rect(15,25,180,260);
$pdf->SetMargins(30,30,30,30);
$pdf->SetFont('HELVETICA','B',42);  
$pdf->Text(18,40,'ORDER CONFIRMATION');  

$pdf->SetFont('HELVETICA','',30);  
$pdf->Text(25,70,'THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL');  

$pdf->SetFont('HELVETICA','',16);  
$pdf->Text(25,100,'PLACE THIS INSIDE THE SHIPPING CARTON WITH THE');  
$pdf->Text(75,110,'CONTROL BOARD');  
$pdf->Text(25,130,'WRITE THE BELOW ORDER CONFIRMATION NUMBER ON');  
$pdf->Text(45,140,'THE OUTSIDE OF THE SHIPPING CARTON');  

$ordernumber = '2000000546';
$pdf->SetFont('HELVETICA','B',16);  
$pdf->Text(45,160,"(Order Confirmation Number: ".$ordernumber.") ");  


$pdf2 = new PDF_Code128();
$pdf2->AddPage();
$pdf2->SetFont('HELVETICA','',10);

$code='2000000546';
$pdf2->Code128(50,20,$code,80,20);
$pdf2->SetXY(50,45);
$pdf2->Write(5,$code);
$pdf2->Output();


$pdf->SetFont('HELVETICA','',30);  
$pdf->Text(25,260,'THIS IS NOT A SHIPPING LABEL');  

$pdf->Output();  

?>
```

I want to show Text and Barcode on Same PDF Page however only one is showing either Barcode or text.

Below Is my expected output -

[expected pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYMvv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
$pdf2 = new PDF_Code128();
```

Then replace `$pdf2` with `$pdf`.

And finally replace:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

with:

```
$pdf = new PDF_Code128();
```

You may remove the additional `AddPage()` call, too.

Now you have a single instance of `PDF_Code128`. Before you created two different instances while you only output the initial instance.